# Windows 10 UAP deploy code 705 and DEP0700 / DEP6100 / DEP6200

Tags: visual-studio-2015, windows-10, win-universal-app, windows-10-mobile

I'm trying to make a new version of my apps to target w10 with Visual Studio 2015 community on a surface pro (v1).
I installer w10 with the update and Visual studio 2015 community final version.

I create a new project (or download a sample, same result), i try to debug. Tells me it needs to be deployed first. Ok, i try to deploy on device (or simulator, same result) and i get the error:
CopyWin32Resources failed with exit code 705

Windows has the developper mode active.

If i try to test a "Release" on "Local Machine", i get : 
Error : DEP0700 : Registration of the app failed. Windows ne peut pas déployer sur le chemin d'accès Release au type de système de fichiers exFAT. (0x80073cfd)
(which means "Windows can not to the Release path of the file system type exFat").

If i create a Windows Phone 8.1 Hub app and run it on the Windows 10 512mb emulator, i get the following errors:
Error : DEP6100 : The following unexpected error occurred during bootstrapping stage 'Connecting to the device '8BDF218D-FDBB-4A97-90F9-3AA33B559A92'.': 
Error : DEP6200 : Bootstrapping 'Mobile Emulator 10.0.10240.0 WVGA 4 inch 512MB' failed. Device cannot be found.
There isn't any problem with the 8.1 512mb emulator.

I can run the Windows 10 emulator with the command line:
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft XDE\10.0.10240.0\XDE.exe" /name "Mobile Emulator 10.0.10240.0 WVGA 4 inch 512MB.conta" /displayName "Mobile Emulator 10.0.10240.0 WVGA 4 inch 512MB" /vhd "C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Emulation\Mobile\10.0.10240.0\Flash.vhd" /video "480x854" /memsize 512 /diagonalSize 4 /language 409 /bootlanguage 409 /creatediffdisk "C:\Users\conta\AppData\Local\Microsoft\XDE\10.0.10240.0\dd.480x854.512.vhd" /snapshot  /fastShutdown
where "conta" is my windows username.
Even with the emulator started (and visible in Hyper-v), i'm back to the "CopyWin32Resources faile with exit 705" error with a Windows 10 app and the DEP6100 and DEP6200 with a Windows 8 app on the Windows 10 emulator.

Does anyone would have an idea of why please ?
Thank you.

Comment: In the windows 10 settings.  Go to update & security make sure you have selected developer mode under For Developers

Comment: I should have write that Windows is in developper mode... And the same error nappées with the simulator

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ok, on the surface pro, i have a sdcard. I use to put all my datas (and source code) on it and it seems to be the source of my problems.

If i create a Windows 10 project in my c:\ drive, folder by default, i can deploy and debug my Windows 10 apps.

This is only a partial solution (local machine) because i still have the problems to debug in Windows 10 mobile emulators. There is solution (not working for me) from Nicolas Delabarre here: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/fr-FR/ea4e016c-2ea6-4b2c-b507-dcc91b31c904/probleme-lancement-application?forum=winstoreappsfr
In regedit, add the key:
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\SirepClient]
"DisableProtocol3"=dword:00000001
then restart Visual Studio

Answer (score 3):

I have a Surface Pro 4 and I use the SD card to keep all my documents including my code. I had the same issue where I could not debug the code and tried the solution proposed by Netah, I added the registry key but it did not solve my problem.

The solution that worked for me was to change the output path (right click project, select Properties -> Build tab -> Output path) to a folder in the C: drive and it worked perfectly well.

[image: OutputPath]

Answer (score 0):

705 should be the ERROR_FT_WRITE_RECOVERY mentioned on System Error Codes [(500-999)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms681388(v=vs.85).aspx) .

Per my experience, there are many possible causes for this kind of issue.

Try the following see if you can make any progress.

1. Run visual studio in safe mode, and try re-deploying. open developer command prompt -> type devenv -safemode
2. Shut down third party anti-virus or scan software you installed. And try again. Sometimes, shutting down cannot fully stop them. Temporarily uninstalling them is also worth to try.

If above steps cannot avoid the issue, I am afraid you may need to repair your windows because it's likely something(registry maybe) corrupted.

Comment: Opening an existing project, i get "Unsupported
This version of Visual Studio is unable to open the following projects. The project types may not be installed or this version of Visual Studio may not support them...." and i Can not create a new one. I will sadly try a new Windows 10 installation from Start (the current was a migration from Windows 8.1 with almost only Photoshop and Visual Studio installed on the surface). Thank you for your help.

Comment: Just clean reinstalled Windows 10 pro + Visual Studio 2015 community (and only that), create a new blank Windows 10 universal app and still get the same error ! :'(   If anyone has any idea, thank you !

Answer (score 0):

I was also facing the same issue. I fixed it by changing Solutions Platform from x86 to x64.

It appears to me that you were trying to run x86 build on your x64 based OS and VS. Though VS has installed x64 version of emulator only. Hope this works for you.